# How to generate this sequence using python

Tags: python, python-itertools

For example if q = 2, then i have to generate all sequence between [1,1] to [2,2].
if q = 3, then generate sequence between [1,1,1] to [3,3,3]. for q = 4, then generate sequence between [1,1,1,1] to [4,4,4,4], etc..

example of sequence .
for q = 3

```
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 1)
(1, 3, 2)
(1, 3, 3)
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(2, 3, 2)
(2, 3, 3)
(3, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 1, 3)
(3, 2, 1)
(3, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 3)
(3, 3, 1)
(3, 3, 2)
(3, 3, 3)
```

i have tried this "[Python generating all nondecreasing sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552101/python-generating-all-nondecreasing-sequences)"  but not getting the required output.

currently i am using this code,

```
import itertools

def generate(q):
    k = range(1, q+1) * q
    ola = set(i for i in itertools.permutations(k, q))
    for i in sorted(ola):
        print i

generate(3)
```

i need another and good way to generate this sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use itertools.product with the repeat parameter:

```
q = 2
list(itertools.product(range(1, q + 1), repeat=q))
Out: [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

q = 3

list(itertools.product(range(1, q + 1), repeat=q))
Out: 
[(1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 3),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 2),
 ...
```

Comment: So clean and simple!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `itertools.product()`, which does all possible combinations of the iterable elements. `itertools.permutations()` does not repeat elements, and `itertools.combinations()` or `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()` only goes in sorted order (e.g. the first element of the input iterable won't be the last element of the result).

```
from itertools import product

def generate(q):
    assert q > 0  # not defined for <= 0
    return list(product(range(1,q+1), repeat=q))

generate(3)  # [(1,1,1), (1,1,2), ..., (3,3,2), (3,3,3)]
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html